# Google App Engine: Disabling Precompilation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

According to GAE docs you can disable pre-compilation via:

```
<precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>
```

But no where in the docs do they say what the pros/cons/caveats of doing so are. Can any experienced GAE gurus weigh-in on how GAE apps behave when this is enabled vs. disabled?

Specifically, I'm interested in:

- How enabling/disabling this affects runtime performance
- How enabling/disabling this affects billing/costs

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how precompilation is implemented (so this would in detail be best answered by Google guys lurking here), but some insight is given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398738/how-does-google-app-engine-precompile-java).

I'd only add that precompilation should not only speed-up first request after instance is started (cold-start), but all requests when a particular class is used for the first time.  Beyond that it should not improve runtime performance.